# Powershell Pipeline filter

Tags: powershell

I have a WMI query to get the memory usage on a remote server:

```
$w3wpresult = (get-wmiobject Win32_Process -filter "commandline like '%serviceoptimization%'" -computername $server -ErrorAction Stop| select ({$_.privatepagecount / 1gb}) 
$vmresult = (get-wmiobject Win32_Process -filter "commandline like '%serviceoptimization%'" -computername $server -ErrorAction Stop| select ({$_.virtualsize / 1gb}))
```

Output:

```
IP  21Aug2015   0939    @{$_.privatepagecount / 1gb=1.0206184387207}    @{$_.virtualsize / 1gb=1.77864074707031}
IP  21Aug2015   0939    @{$_.privatepagecount / 1gb=0.945835113525391}  @{$_.virtualsize / 1gb=1.72514343261719}
```

I do not want the `@{$.privatepagecount / 1gb=` part of the string.
I just want to see the numeric value for the memory.

How do I do this?
Any input is greatly appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Select-Object with that type of scriptblock for a custom property. Instead, build it this way using a hash table and specifying a label and expression:

```
@{L='PrivatePageCountGB';E={$_.privatepagecount / 1gb}}
```

Putting it together to look like this:

```
$w3wpresult = get-wmiobject Win32_Process -filter "commandline like '%serviceoptimization%'" -computername $server -ErrorAction Stop| 
select @{L='PrivatePageCountGB';E={$_.privatepagecount / 1gb}}

$vmresult = get-wmiobject Win32_Process -filter "commandline like '%serviceoptimization%'" -computername $server -ErrorAction Stop| 
select @{L='VirtualSizeGB';E={$_.virtualsize / 1gb}}
```

If you *only* care about the value, then this would work as well.

```
$w3wpresult = (get-wmiobject Win32_Process -filter "commandline like '%serviceoptimization%'" -computername $server -ErrorAction Stop).privatepagecount /1GB
$vmresult = (get-wmiobject Win32_Process -filter "commandline like '%serviceoptimization%'" -computername $server -ErrorAction Stop).virtualsize/1GB
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.
I had it like this before, but I want the "$w3wpResult" object to only hold the numerical value of the Memory.

the $w3wpResult is later placed in a text file which'll be imported into excel. So the Label is not needed.

is there any way to do this?